# How to prevent printing duplicate record in blade foreach while using model relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using laravel 9.11
I have a stock table containing items and each item is related to a specific place,
[table snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvrdE.png)

I have another form to make changes of values and I want to loop throw all places that exist in stock table but withouh making duplicate record.

snapshot of the error

[showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmMFZ.png)

I do have all record of stock places and made a loop throw it but I want a way to avoid duplicating the records.

**Blade code**

```
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="place_name" class="block mb-2 mt-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400">
                        Select a Place
                    </label>
                    <select id="place_name" name="selectPlace"
                     class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 cursor-pointer">
                        <option selected value="">Choose a Place</option>
                        
                        @foreach($stocks as $stock)
                            <option value="{{ $stock->places->id }}">{{ $stock->places->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    @error('selectPlace') <p class="input_validate">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
                </div>
```

**Controller code**

```
    public function transfer() {
    $assets = Asset::all();
    $places = Place::all();
    $quantities = AssetQuantity::all();
    $services = Service::all();
    $stocks = Stock::all();

    return view('stock.transfer', [
        'assets' => $assets,
        'places' => $places,
        'quantities' => $quantities,
        'services' => $services,
        'stocks' => $stocks
    ]);
}
```

**Stock Model**

```
    class Stock extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['current_stock', 'asset_id', 'place_id', 'quantity_id'];

    public function assets() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Asset::class, 'asset_id');
    }

    public function places() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Place::class, 'place_id');
    }

    // Relation to know quantity of assets
    public function quantity() {
        return $this->belongsTo(AssetQuantity::class, 'quantity_id');
    }
}
```

**Place Model**

```
class Place extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function stocks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Stock::class, 'place_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code any same data ?

Comment: Show `stocks` model, please. Either that `CS2` is duplicate in database (which I don't suspect) or the relationships (if any) are messing up, guessing the latter.

Comment: Also, if you have a relationship defined between stocks and places, why not use `$stocks = Stock::with('places')->get();` instead?

Comment: sorry I thouht it worked but when I add another place in place list wihout adding a new item that related to stock it still appear in the options.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can eager load `Stock::with('places')->get()` and later map your collection

with something like.

```
$stocksCollection = Stock::with('places')->get();
$collection = $stocksCollection->map(function ($array) {
    return collect($array)->unique('place_id')->all();
});
```